# Mechanics-Maths

Tags: kinematics

Particles $A$ and $B$ are moving along horizontal straight lines which lie in the west east direction. At a certain time, $A$ passes a point $P$ moving to the east with speed $5$ ms$^{-1}$ and constant acceleration $1$ ms$^{-2}$. Simultaneously, $B$ passes a point $Q$ east of $P$ with speed $4$ ms$^{-1}$ towards the west but with constant acceleration $2$ ms$^{-2}$ towards the east. Given that the distance $PQ$ is $28$ m, Calculate

a) The distance of $A$ from $P$ when $B$ reverse direction

b) The time taken after the start for $A$ to overtake

c) The further time taken for $B$ to overtake $A$

Comment: Please show us what u have done..

Comment: i posted the question because i cant figure out any of a,b and c

Comment: add whatever u have done, to the question... Questions with no efforts get downvoted.

Comment: Could you also help and i will try my best

Comment: v=u+at v=0 as B has reversed so 0=4-2t so t=2 seconds s=5(2)+1/2(2)^2=12

Comment: what does ms^{-2} mean?